# I keep getting ValueError in my Python program

Tags: python-3.7

I'm trying to open a csv file for my python book project and this error keeps popping up
`File "c:\Users\MSFT Surface Pro 3\Documents\Programming\Python\Python AIO\Code.py", line 13, in <module>    birthYear = int(row[1] or 0) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' 1/11/2011'`
and this is super annoying, help me please!

Comment: Please post the relevant code and some sample data that displays the problem.

Comment: Well, the error message is correct: `' 1/11/2011'` isn't an integer.

Comment: int call in the line 13 of code.py is producing this error. Use int(birthdate_string[-4:]) to get the year from the date string '1/11/2011'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like line 13 in in Code.py is `birthYear = int(row[1] or 0)`, but probably should be something like `birthYear = row[1] or ""`.